# add pixels to dynamic iframe height

Tags: javascript, iframe, height

I am trying to add a fixed amount of pixels to a dynamic iframe height. How do I add a static amount of pixels to my iframe height? I am using this javascript to adjust the iframe height according to its content:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    // Set specific variable to represent all iframe tags.
    var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    // Resize heights.
    function iResize()
    {
        // Iterate through all iframes in the page.
        for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++)
        {
            // Set inline style to equal the body height of the iframed content.
            iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
        }
    }

    // Check if browser is Safari or Opera.
    if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera)
    {
        // Start timer when loaded.
        $('iframe').load(function()
            {
                setTimeout(iResize, 0);
            }
        );

        // Safari and Opera need a kick-start.
        for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++)
        {
            var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
            iFrames[i].src = '';
            iFrames[i].src = iSource;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // For other good browsers.
        $('iframe').load(function()
            {
                // Set inline style to equal the body height of the iframed content.
                this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
            }
        );

    }
}
```

);

When I add for example the number '100' before 'px', it just puts 100 next to the current iframe height. So if my iframe height is 200, the height will be 200100 if I use this:

```
iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + '100px';
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I add for example the number '100' before 'px', it just puts 100 next to the current iframe height. So if my iframe height is 200, the height will be 200100

Since `+` is the operator for string concatenation as well as the normal “plus” operator, this happens when you are already in a string context.

Try using `parseInt` on the `iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight` value to convert it into a number, so that the following `+` *adds* 100 instead of concatenating it:

```
iFrames[i].style.height =
  ( parseInt(iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight) + 100 ) + 'px';
```